# Some desktop items are missing

Tags: windows-7

So I have kind of a weird situation happening. On my laptop, there are icons missing from the desktop for things that are saved there. If I browse through explorer and select desktop, I see everything that is suppoed to be there. The ones that are chosen to be viewed seems to be random each day. It is just confusing as to why only some are shown and not all.

I don't have many items on there (around 20) so its not a matter of there being too many.  I have tried a simple right click and refresh, toggling "show icons" off then on, and still no solution. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you run virus and malware scans? Does it do this in all profiles? How about in Safe Mode?

Comment: I have checked for malware. None found. I am unsure about other profiles as this is a work computer so I don't have the flexibility to add other users. I can get back to you about safe mode

Comment: You may want to talk to your IT department before making too many changes or attempting other things.

Comment: Yeah. I will soon. It frustraters me sometimes having to go through them if I know an answer is all but I guess that is the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking settings in Registry should fix this issue!

1. Open up Registry
2. Then in the Registry Editor program. follow this folder path route
   `HKEY_LOCAL MACHINE / SOFTWARE / Microsoft / WINDOWS NT / CurrenVersion / Winlogon`
3. Now click on  Winlogon and after clicking then look right side pane.

Here you have to find the Item called `“shell”` and click on twice (Double click)
In the Value Data Edit box, Type Explorer.exe (The value od this key “Eplorer.exe) then click on OK
Now restart your computer, and after restart Problem will be fixed.

Comment: Hm interesting idea however it is already set to explorer.exe